# TeleBot, How to make bot auto reply message after 10mins

Tags: python, bots, telegram, chatbot

**TeleBot**, how to set it schedule send after user send message to our bot, i want it auto reply to user after *10mins*

Answer (score 0):

If by TeleBot you mean a Telegram-Bot then you have two options:

a) put in a CRON-Job that triggers a response function after given time

or

b) If it is okay that the process is inactive/unavailable for 10 mins then you can just let the programm sleep for 10 minutes (which is probably not what you want by using a chatbot because this would make the bot miss messages in that time if those are not buffered anywhere).

If neither fits your problem, please give us more information on the problem